# Rule to extract maximum of each array

Tags: replacement, rule

I have made a rule that extracts the maximum value from a array of two values:

```
{3, 1} /. {aa_, bb_} -> Max[{aa, bb}]
```

returns 3.
Now I would like to generalize this rule and define myNEWrule such that:

```
{{3, 1},{0,5}} /.myNEWrule
```

should return {3,5}.
how to make this efficiently?
thanks

Comment: Why not just `Max` and `Max/@`?

Comment: Your solution returns the maximum of the first and the maximum of the second column. I am looking for finding the maximum of each {a,b} element. their number is arbitrary.
Eg: {{3,1},{0,5},{1,2}} should be replaced by {3,5,2} and so on.

Comment: I don't think so. `Max /@ {{3, 1},{0,5}}` goes over rows, for arbitrary number of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a more robust implementation of your rule that will work on any list of numeric pairs.

```
SeedRandom[0]; pairs = RandomInteger[42, {12, 2}]
```

> `{{41, 32}, {33, 22}, {15, 3}, {30, 34}, {4, 14}, {24, 28}, 
>   {10, 42}, {10, 12}, {42, 21}, {31, 33}, {5, 36}, {15, 0}}`

```
pairs /. u : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} :> Max[u]
```

> `{41, 33, 15, 34, 14, 28, 42, 12, 42, 33, 36, 15}`

```
SeedRandom[0]; reals = RandomReal[1., {6, 2}]
```

> `{{0.652468, 0.63307}, {0.682813, 0.566352}, {0.935202, 0.976188}, 
>   {0.238452, 0.637562}, {0.101098, 0.645525}, {0.159522, 0.813788}}`

```
reals /. u : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} :> Max[u]
```

> `{0.652468, 0.682813, 0.976188, 0.637562, 0.645525, 0.813788}`

Still I would remind you, that as others have said, mapping `Max` over a list of numeric pairs will be more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to modify your existing rule at all. Let's define it via `rule = {aa_, bb_} -> Max[{aa, bb}]`. Now use

```
Replace[{{3, 1}, {0, 5}}, rule, 1]
(*{3,5}*)
```

That being said, it would probably be more efficient to simply use `Map[Max, {{3, 1}, {0, 5}}]`.

Comment: both your proposals work well. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should work easy.

```
list = {{3, 1}, {0, 5}};
Table[list[[i]] /. {aa_, bb_} -> Max[{aa, bb}], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

Following Kuba's remark, this is more safe:

```
Table[Max@list[[i]] , {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

Comment: Unless aa or bb have global values. You may want to use `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: I've edited my answer @Kuba.